# jQueryUI Autocomplete dropdown missing formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to get jQueryUI Autocomplete to function in a local test page.

It looks fine on their demo page:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

However when I run it locally, with exactly the same demo code (with remote calls removed) it works fine, except the dropdown box doesn't display, just an ugly list with the ugly default black li bullets:

[image: ugly formatting]

So there's something outside of the code on that page formatting the ul into a cleaner dropdown menu.  I don't see it. I could probably style it myself in a few minutes, but I'd rather just get this to work correctly.

And here's their demo code, tweaked to run locally against an array instead:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote datasource</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  .ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: ["abc","def"],
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
  <input id="birds">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant reproduce it. The demo code seems working.. Do you have any errors in console?

```js
$( function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: ["abc","def"],
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
      }
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
  background: white url("https://jqueryui.com/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
}
</style>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
  <input id="birds">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, the problem was that I was using a protocol-relative link:
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
which obviously fails from the local file system... Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the problem in your source code, but this also happens when you forget to add the jquery style sheet in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ref="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

This may help others.